# PHP MySQL - How to delete row based on input text

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to delete a row specified on input setted by the user in the input text. My problem is that: when I click on the button *DELETE* all the rows are deleted, not only the one specified by the user. I'm using Zend Framework version 1.12.

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="Cancteam"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="button1" name="delete">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

PHP

```
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
         
      $id = $_POST['Cancteam'];
      $DeleteTeam = new TableTeam();
      $where = $DeleteTeam->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id_team' , $id);
      $DeleteTeam->delete($where);
    
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    
    
    
   $id = $_POST['Cancteam'];

   
  $DeleteTeam = new TableTeam();
  $where = $DeleteTeam->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id_team = ?', $id);
  $DeleteTeam->delete($where);
  
  
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `$_POST['Cancteam']` in php file? just `echo $_POST['Cancteam']` it and do `exit(1);`

Comment: The value of $_POST['Cancteam'] is the value setted by the user in input. I tried to echo $id (the variable where it's saved $_POST['Cancteam'] ) and it works. For example if I put 1 in the input text and press the button delete the echo is equal to 1.

Comment: You just proved your post value is correct so your delete statement has to be faulty.

Comment: @SJacks yes, sure my delete statement need to be adjusted, but I don't know how.

Comment: You could find this out by echoing the value of the variables associated with the query, for instance echo $where; So do your if statement then just echo all the variables until you see where the problem lies.